# Does Webpack 1 support 'include' and 'exclude' within loaders?

Tags: webpack

Does Webpack 1.* support the include and exclude options within a loader? I can not find documentation saying it does, nor does the Webpack-1 github branch have any examples containing it.

```
{
  // ....
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
         test: '\.js',
         include: [/node_modules/],
         exclude: [/extra_srcs/]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders). As noted in those docs, `include` is preferable over `exclude`, when possible. Those docs also suggest that `exclude` should be a condition, so an array may not work there. Using your example:

```
{
  // ....
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [/node_modules/],
        exclude: /extra_srcs/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```